# Store last generated number and generate +1 based on that number on the portal.

Tags: apex, customer-portal

I want Salesforce to generate a number on the portal it needs to go from 0000 to 9999 and it needs to be generated once the customer choses a number. eg, if the last generated number was 0021 and the customer presses 3 the numbers generated will be 0022 0023 0024. Where in salesforce would i store the last generated number only without storing all the previous numbers ? Any idea on how to approach this problem ? any guidence or tips would be usefull thank you .

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent an auto-number field?

Comment: By "customer" do you mean a User? If so you can add a field to the User object and increment that.

Comment: yes by customer I mean a portal user. one that can access the community/ portal but not the salesfroce insance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom setting (or an object in this case your object will need only 1 record that will contain that number) and store that number there. Then once it is changed just update that number.

For example create a Hierarchy Custom Setting *Number Setting* and add a number field there called *Largest Number*. Then add a default Organization Level Value - your start value i.e. 0:

```
Number_settings__c setting = Number_Setting__c.getOrgDefaults(); 
Double largest = setting.Largest_Number__c;

// Display value of the variable largest where you need to 
// Do some manipulations i.e. increment your number
// Assign your largest number to a variable largest

setting.Largest_Number__c = largest;
update setting;
```

This way that custom setting will keep your largest number.

Comment: Can you add some detail to make this a more complete answer?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've added some more details.

Comment: Why not use `Hierarchy Custom Setting` and `getOrgDefault()`?

Comment: Not too clear from the question, but I would assume there are many customers not one customer.

Comment: I was thinking that number is one for all users. But if this is not the case we can use user Id as a name instead of Largest. Good point with hierarchy settings I'll update my answer once I'll get to my computer:)

Comment: @AdrianLarson thanks, I've updated my answer with Hierarchy CS.

Comment: Should be easy to modify to use on a per-user basis as well.

Comment: Additionally, it could be interesting to make these custom settings hidden so that an admin user cannot fiddle with them

Comment: Where would I put this formula ? I can't seem to be able to put it inside of the number field

Comment: It is not possible with the standard functionality like formulas. You have to write some apex code to do that.

Comment: Actually you can reference Hierarchy CS through formulas. It's pretty slick. Iirc it gets the most specific instance possible, so it will use fallbacks.